# Angular Material ui radio buttons get value

Tags: angular, angular-material, radio-button

I'm having issues with Angular Material UI radio buttons. It seems silly that at this point I need to ask a question about how to get the value of the radio buttons but I just can't seem to make it work on the project that I'm working on.

In my project, I have one card with radio buttons to choose a value and 3 cards with sliders to choose a value. A card will be active when its clicked on and when the form is submitted I check for the card that is active ( by chicken if the array id == to selectedIndex) and only pass that value. With the sliders, it worked perfectly but with the radio buttons, I struggled to set the value in my object array to the checked radio box.

I tried different things like working with ngModel and setting it to skillExpArr.value but that didn't work and adding a form control radValue that could hold the value before assigning it to the array. Anyone who could explain to me how to do it properly?

html

```
 <mat-card *ngFor="let skillExp of skillExpArr;" [class.active]="selectedIndex === skillExp.id" (click)="selectedIndex = skillExp.id">
                        <div *ngIf="!skillExp.slider ;else slider">


                            <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
                                <mat-radio-button name="value" value="1" [formControl]="radValue"  >I followed a workshop / <br>
                                    played around with it</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button name="value" value="5" [formControl]="radValue"  >Played with it for a week ,<br>
                                    I know the basics</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button name="value" value="10"  [formControl]="radValue"   >Two weeks of experience </mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button name="value" value="20"[formControl]="radValue"   >I have my first solid <br>
                                    month of experience</mat-radio-button>

                            </mat-radio-group>

                        </div>
</mat-card>
 <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onFormSubmit( skillExpArr[selectedIndex].value )">Add experience</button>
```

.ts

```
  radValue = new FormControl('');
  selectedIndex = 0;

  skillExpArr: Array<any> = [
    {
      id: 0,
      level: 'Rookie',
      title: " I'm soooo new to this ",
      value: 0,
      imgPath: '../../../../../assets/JPG/rookie-exp.jpg',
      enabled: false,
      slider: false,
    },  
       ... ]

  onFormSubmit(experience) {
    console.log('form submitted and value = ', expiernece);
    console.log('radio=', this.radValue.value)

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `[(ngModel)]="skillExp.value"` to `<mat-radio-group>`

Hope to help u !

Comment: I always added ngModel to the radio button itself. Never to the radio group. Thanks for your answer!